# Unable to simulate transaction on mainnet

Tags: wallet, transaction, mainnet

Unable to simulate transaction on mainnet.

This was working fine just a few days ago. Without me deploying any updates to the site, it all of a sudden stopped working when I checked today. It is unable to simulate the transaction where I am sending 3500 custom SPL tokens.

Any suggestion on what might have caused this sudden change in behaviour despite no code changes made?

If I approve it, it still works properly... 3500 tokens get deducted correctly and everything works fine.

[image: Phantom Wallet View]

Comment: Phantom did an update to their wallet recently. Maybe worth writing their support. Maybe see if it works using another wallet to see if it is actually a phantom problem. Your screenshot looks like the simulation works just fine. Maybe you are trying to send the tokens to the same token acccount or something?